# How to setup PHPMyAdmin as SubDomain on Apache 2.4.7?

Tags: apache2, lamp, phpmyadmin, apache2.4

I'm currently having issues setting up PHPMyAdmin as a subdomain. I was able to do this on Ubuntu 12.04 no problem but since upgrading can't seem to get it properly configured. Here's the conf I'm trying to load:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/share/phpmyadmin"
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
    php_flag track_vars On
    php_flag register_globals Off
    php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
    php_value include_path .
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
    php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/$
    </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    # AllowOverride All
    # Require all granted
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    # AllowOverride All
    # Require all granted
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you update your question with error you got?

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps. I'm going to use 'example' as the file/subdomain name. You can name it something like 'phpmyadmin'

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf
```

Add this inside example.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin user@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias example.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin

        <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Save the file and then from your terminal run

```
sudo a2ensite example.conf
```

Now just restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

That's all you have to do for it to work in Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4.7 and to get to your PHPMyAdmin just type this in your browser.

```
http://example.domain.com
```

Comment: you are missing the closing `</VirtualHost>`